# Whats the proper way to use mongoose population?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas setup:

```
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema);
```

And

```
var PlaceSchema = new Schema({
  client: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client'},
  address: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Place', PlaceSchema);
```

If i get a list of places, i can populate the client easily like this:

```
Place.find({}).populate('client')
```

However, if i want to get a list of all the clients and all of their places, how would i make a query for that? Should i just simply loop through all of the clients and finding the places for it with `Place.find({client:client._id)` before returning the response?

Answer (score 0):

This data structure would only work in one way, PlaceSchema do refer to ClientSchema but ClientSchema do not have any reference to PlaceSchema, the solution would be to define your ClientSchema this way :

```
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    _address: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Place'}]
});
```

It seems kinda dumb but it would be much easier for your case

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have a number of places they will have their own unique ids, and for every place a client is connected to, you can have an array of placeId, you can push a placeId to this array everytime a client is connected to this place.`

```
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    _address: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Place'}]
});`
```